# Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: No such file or directory: I am lost

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I know this has been asked before, but there were no answers to the other questions. I have also tried everything I can find to fix this but am having no luck.

```
2>Detecting installed packages...
2>Removing old runtime: Mono.Android.DebugRuntime...
2>Target device is armeabi-v7a.
2>Installing the Mono shared runtime (debug - 1466444585)...
2>:Deployment failed
2>Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: No such file or directory
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Util.AggregateAsyncResult.CheckError(CancellationToken token)
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbSyncClient.EndPush(IAsyncResult result)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult  iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
2>The "InstallPackageAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
2>System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: No such file or directory
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Util.AggregateAsyncResult.CheckError(CancellationToken token)
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbSyncClient.EndPush(IAsyncResult result)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>c__async1.MoveNext()
2>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<StartAsync>c__async0.MoveNext()
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait() 
2>   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.InstallPackageAssemblies.Execute()
2>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
2>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
2>---> (Inner Exception #0) Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: No such file or directory
2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Util.AggregateAsyncResult.CheckError(CancellationToken token)
 2>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbSyncClient.EndPush(IAsyncResult result)
2>   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>c__async1.MoveNext()
2>--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2>   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<StartAsync>c__async0.MoveNext()<---
```

I get this error when making a brand new blank app. I have tried reinstalling everything, changing java versions, getting different versions of the sdk and installing every version I could from the sdk manager. Is there anything else anyone could suggest I try? If it helps I am using Visual Studio 2015 on windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after two weeks of trying to find an answer to this problem I think I solved it. I noticed my emulator would start up and never get past the android boot screen, and figured that would be my next step in trying to fix it. So I installed revo uninstaller and uninstalled the Android SDK completely. Reinstalled it, and was finally getting different errors that seem to be quite common and easy to fix with a simple google search. I hope this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you run the Android SDK, emulator, Visual studio, etc. as Administrator. This fixed the issue for me. "Run as Administrator"!

Comment: What i did was a factory reset of the emulator and it worked. I also installed all recommended Visual Studio updates.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which worked for me:

- Right click on your android project and go to properties
- Then select android options
- Then uncheck the checkbox labeled "Use fast deployments"

Then the emulator will be able to run without any problem. This is an issue, and The bug was reported on github a few months ago, here is a [reference](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4996#issuecomment-672121497)